# Change IP address of Team Foundation Server 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I work on a project on a microsoft team foundation server 2013. the IP address of team foundation server machine changed by administrator of our network and our visual studio clients don't work now. we can connect again to new IP address and get latest version of project but our files changes lost. we don't check-in project before changing IP address of server machine. How we can keep project changes and change IP address of tfs? How to update solution with new server info?

Comment: is your connection string IP based or FQDN based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use friendly DNS names in your environment so that you can make sure that no matter when your environment changes - disaster recovery, upgrades, topology changes, etc. - that your team will always be able to connect to all of the components of Team Foundation Server.  I wrote a blog post about this approach here:  http://www.edsquared.com/2011/01/03/Using+Friendly+DNS+Names+In+Your+TFS+Environment.aspx

There are several DNS names that I recommend separate from the one most people think about using.  I hope that will help you moving forward.

[image: Using Friendly DNS Names with Team Foundation Server]

Answer (score 2):

You can manually edit your host file to reroute your old TFS ip address to the new server. This way, all your Visual Studio clients can connect and checkin there changes.

After this is finished, you can remove the host file edit and just connect to the new environment.

[This page contains some good info](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) on how to change your host file.

Comment: I suggest to use this as a temporary measure than apply Ed suggestion to prevent this happen again.